# Rails Paperclip delete local attachment if upload successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have the code below to save my local file to AWS S3. It uploads my file to S3 correctly, but then my local file is not deleted. Now I've filled disk space completely. How can I ask paperclip to remove local file after it has uploaded it?

```rb
class JobArtifact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :remote_url
  has_attached_file :file, path: 'tmp/:id/:fingerprint.:extension'

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :file

  def remote_url=(url)
    self.file = URI.parse(url_value)

    @remote_url = url
  end
end
```

It is called this way:

```rb
@filename = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/values.csv"
JobArtifact.create(file: File.open(@filename))
```

Comment: Why are you storing the file locally in the first place? You can directly store it to s3.

Comment: @Gautam Good point. I'm building it locally. It can be up to 20M. Then I push it to S3. Can I build a CSV to S3 line by line?

Comment: ok, I got your point and I am not sure if you can build a CSV to S3 line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you know the path of the file you can just do something like this after it's uploaded to s3 -

```
def remove_file
  File.delete(@filename) if File.exist?(@filename)
end
```

Comment: check this out - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1004